# Where is my program pulling random numbers from?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm working on a challenge on codingame.com, to find the integer (positive or negative) closest to zero. The code I wrote works for FOUR out of SIX challenges. The other two, I get output that is entirely unexpected, outside of the input.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

/**
 * Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
 * the standard input according to the problem statement.
 **/
class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt(); // the number of temperatures to analyse
        //Variables declared here below
        int[] temps =  new int[n];
        int closest = 0;
        // DO I NEED THIS NEXT BLOCK??!!
        //if (in.hasNextLine()) 
        //{
        //    in.nextLine();
        //}
        //For loop here, to take the input from in.nextInt()
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
           //int closest = temps[0];
           temps[i] = in.nextInt();
           closest = Math.abs(temps[0]);
           //System.err.println(temps[i]);
           if (closest > 0)
           {
            if (closest > i)
            {
               closest = i;
            }

           }
           else if (closest < 0)
           {
             if (closest < i)
             {
                 closest = i;
             }
           }
        }

        //String temps = in.nextLine(); // the n temperatures expressed as integers ranging from -273 to 5526

        // Write an action using System.out.println()
        // To debug: System.err.println("Debug messages...");
        System.err.println("Final Results: n = " + n);
        System.err.println("Temps are: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            System.err.println(temps[i]);
        }
        System.err.println("Closest to zero is " + closest);
        System.out.println(closest);
    }
}
```

[image: This is the output, with debugging, of my code]

Comment: Have you debugged it? And you haven't included near enough information. You haven't even said what you expect it to produce.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Is expected Result is -5? The question is not clear.

Comment: If you set `closest = Math.abs(...);`, how do you expect `else if (closest < 0)` to *ever* be true? You do know what [`abs()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-) does, right?

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback, I'll pull this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your for loop is doing what you want it to do. Like, at all.

```
temps[i] = in.nextInt();  // This is sensible enough
closest = Math.abs(temps[0]); // Every time your loop runs, the closest value to 0 is... the absolute value of the first int in the array?
//System.err.println(temps[i]);
if (closest > 0)  // This is only false if closest is 0
    {
        if (closest > i) // This makes the outer if redundant, since i >= 0. It's also not clear what the point of this condition even is
        {
           closest = i; // Here's the big one: you're setting closest to your iterator, the index of the current number in the array instead of the number itself. 
        }
     }
       else if (closest < 0) // This is never true, since absolute values are always >=0
       {
         if (closest < i)
         {
             closest = i;
         }
       }
    }
```

Go through your code, one line at a time, keeping track of the values of each variable, and you'll be able to find both where the numbers you get are coming from and if what you're doing makes any sense.

It looks like you've got most of the right pieces somewhere in there, but they're not being put together properly. When you're revising your algorithm, don't lose sight of your objective: you want to find the number in your list with the least absolute value. You can do this by checking that the absolute value of your next number is less than the current least value.